# Angular 2: *ngFor cause CSS problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I'm building a slider with a coverflow effect, I used the [jquery-flipster](https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster/) plugin for it.

I can import it and make it work like the demo, but when I want to do it dynamicaly with the `*ngFor` directive, the result is just a simple list without the coverflow effect.

I made the working version like this :

```
<div id="coverflow">
        <ul class="flip-items">
            <li>
                <img src="../../../img/text1.gif">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../../../img/text2.gif">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../../../img/text3.gif">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../../../img/text4.gif">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../../../img/text5.gif">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../../../img/text6.gif">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But with the `*ngFor` directive I got this:

[image: what I got with ngFor]

The code :

```
<div id="coverflow">
    <ul class="flip-items">
        <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
            <img [src]="tab.url">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`tabs` is an array where I stock all my pictures url (in a JSON file).

Comment: When did you initailize flipster (e.g. call `$('.my-flipster').flipster();`)  Was it in your ngOnInit method?  The constructor?  Somewhere else?

Comment: In the last line, you meant `tabs` instead of `Tab`, right?

Comment: @Pace I initialize my flipster in ngOninit ,I think the problem come from here, it initialize the flipster when the div is "empty" but I don't know how I could work auround this problem

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes I meant tabs my bad. (Edited)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ngOnInit()` method is too early in the lifecycle to call `$('...').flipster()`  At that point in the lifecycle the dependencies of a component have been injected but the DOM has not been generated so when you call `flipster()` the query it issues will return empty and the plugin can't do anything.

You should use the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle method which will be called once the view and content have been configured by angular.  For an overview of all of the hooks take a look at [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

Finally, if your underlying list is going to be changing at all then you will need to notify the flipster plugin of the change.  I'm not sure if this is as simple as calling `$('...').flipster()` again or if there is something else you have to do to track the changes.  The flipster docs don't seem to mention this case.

Comment: Thank you ! ngOnInit was the problem, changing it by noAfterViewInit resolve the problem.